# How to retrieve records by date ignoring time

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I have a table that contains date/time column with values like `9/11/2012 11:50:08 AM`, `9/11/2012 4:06:19 PM`, `10/11/2012 4:06:19 PM`

How can I retrieve records that date on `'9/11/2012'`?

Comment: Didn't the given answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

This will return in `MM/dd/yyyy`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/11/2012 11:50:08 AM', 101);
```

To get in `dd/MM/yyyy` try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/11/2012 11:50:08 AM', 103);
```

For more see [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [How to convert from string to datetime?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

**EDIT:** (from your comment)

If your query is like `select * from table where Date like '9/11/2012%'` then You need to convert `Date` for that.(assuming your `Date` column is `varchar`)

Your query should be:
If `9/11/2012` is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, DATE, 101) = '9/11/2012'
```

Or if `9/11/2012` is in `dd/MM/yyyy` format try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, DATE, 103) = '9/11/2012'
```

Comment: sir i use
select * from table where Date like '9/11/2012%'

but its not working..any other way to get result ??

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your column is a `datetime` column and you want to fetch all rows that is on a specific date.

In SQL Server 2008 you can cast your `datetime` column to date.

```
select *
from YourTable
where cast(DateTimeCol as date) = '2012-09-11'
```

I would recommend that you use the dateformat `yyyy-mm-dd` for dates in SQL Server 2008 if you need to use string literals.

Even better is if you could use a date parameter.

```
select *
from YourTable
where cast(DateTimeCol as date) = @DateParam
```

Comment: sir i use select * from table where Date like '9/11/2012%' but its not working..any other way to get result ??

Comment: Why don't you try what have provided in my answer instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where convert(date,date_col)='2012-09-11'
```